# MySQL: Connect to a remote Database error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a simple HTML form that that tries to connect to a database hosted on a remote server. The form tries to connect to the  database with the following  script:
(EDITED following davejal suggestions)

```
 <?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('log_errors', 1);
 ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $error='';

 echo "<p>Test</p>" ;
 define('DB_HOST', 'mysql.utk.edu:3306');
 define('DB_NAME', 'emoschan_test');
 define('DB_USER','emoschan');
 define('DB_PASSWORD','NewPass');

echo "   Does mysql  exist?". var_dump(function_exists('mysql_connect'));
echo "   Does mysqli exist?". var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'));
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

if (mysql_connect_error($con)) { echo "Third Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysql_connect_error();  }
else { echo "<p>Successfully connected to your database</p>"; }
?>
```

The connection fails and I receive the followin error ( I include a screenshot of the error):

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

[output when I click "submit" the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu5uX.png)

As you see the mysqli doesn't exist.

I have tried to change the password to the old encryption, still get the error (phpmyadmin screenshot):
[change to OLD password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om6R1.png)

2nd EDIT. phpinfo() shows PHP version 5.3.0 and "Client API version : 4.0.31"

Comment: if you run `phpInfo();` then you will see a lot of information about PHP, version etc. and what drivers are loaded etc.

Comment: @Ryan phpInfo() shows:  PHP version is 5.3.0 and " MYSQL Client API version : 4.0.31"

Comment: try to omit the port on your host path:  

define('DB_HOST', 'mysql.utk.edu');


I had a similar problem recently and solved this way

Answer (score 0):

The function mysql_connect is deprecated.

Comment: you think or you know?

Comment: I have tried the exact same code to connect to localhost (database in my computer) and it works fine

Comment: The mysqli extension is included with PHP versions 5 and later and mysql_connect is deprecated. Maybe you are running a lower php version on your server.

Comment: @Pedro [here is the picture from phpmyadmin](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Om6R1.png) there is a comment on the versions on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

on the line where you declare `$con` change to mysqli so

```
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
```

becomes:

```
$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
```

You can remove the line where you select the db, because you already select it in when creating the connection, by passing it as the fourth variable.

Don't forget to change the if part also to become:

```
if (mysqli_connect_error($con)) { echo "Third Failed to connect to MySQLi:" . mysqli_connect_error();  }
```

to display all errors add the following right after opening `php`

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
 ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
 ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $error='';
```

Comment: I have included this check:    echo "Does mysqli exist?". var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect')); It returns false. mysqli is not included.

Comment: I think you'll need to add mysqli, because mysql is deprecated

Comment: check which errors are thrown with the final part of my edited answer and see what's causing errors

Comment: I get this warning: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client in /home/********/public_html/connectivity-sign-up.php on line 21